# Building a SPFx solution with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, datatables, spfx

I apologize in advance for a wall of text question.  SPFx is a new requirement mandated from on high and I don't have any working experience with it at this point.

I created a vanilla SPFx project added to github to make it easier. There are just too many moving parts to try and get them all in the question.

https://github.com/cyberjetx/dtspfx/tree/AddDt

**Description of problem:**
Trying to make the basic datatable work with zero configuration in SharePoint framework (SPFx) this is new ground for me and it has been mandated from on-high that we will be using SPFx or not on the intranet at all.

I am trying to document the process so that others using dt will have a base to start from or at least be able to see what is needed to to add dt to their SPFxs. This process is started in the readme.md.

in Area51WebPart.ts

```js
import 'datatables.net';
```

in main.js

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();  
});
```

In config.json I would IDEALLY like to just use the combined file from dataTables cdn. I have also tried `npm install --save datatables.net-dt` and linked in config  as `"path": "/node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",` earning the following:

> [17:03:22] Error - [webpack] 'dist':
> "C:\code\dtspfx\node_modules\datatables.net\js\jquery.dataTables.min.js"
> does not exist. Ensure the path is correct and relative to the project
> root.

however, it is indeed there, if I copy and paste the path and open in notepad it's there.

```json
. . .
  "externals": {
    "jquery": {
      "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js",
      "globalName": "jQuery"
    }
    ,"datatables.net": {
        "path": "/node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
     // "path": "https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.12.1/af-2.4.0/b-2.2.3/b-colvis-2.2.3/b-html5-2.2.3/b-print-2.2.3/cr- 1.5.6/date-1.1.2/fc-4.1.0/fh-3.2.4/kt-2.7.0/r-2.3.0/rg-1.2.0/rr-1.2.8/sc-2.0.7/sb-1.3.4/sp-2.0.2/sl-1.4.0/sr-1.1.1/datatables.min.js",
      "globalName": "jQuery",
      "globalDependencies": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    }
  },
. . .
```

Comment: There might be some useful information in this Microsoft walkthrough: [Migrate jQuery and DataTables solution built using Script Editor web part to SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/migrate-jquery-datatables-script-to-spfx)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading slash here => `/node_modules/datatables/...`. It may be looking at the root of your hard drive, not at the root of the project folder.

Other than that, you are probably using a wrong template, you don't need react or typescript if you are not using it. You can use plain javascript to create your webpart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable in SPFx web parts using jQuery and DataTable libraries.

Follow below documentation and web parts for detailed code:

1. [Migrate jQuery and DataTables solution built using Script Editor web part to SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/migrate-jquery-datatables-script-to-spfx)
2. [SharePoint Framework DataTable web part sample](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-datatable)
3. [DataTable Using MUI table](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-datatable-using-mui-tables)